# browserify external dependencies order in html file

Tags: gulp, external, browserify, browserify-shim

I have browserify bundle which uses external lib via browserify-shim. Problem is index.html where i have to manually set the order of included files: first external lib, then browserify bundle - it doesn't work in diffrent order. My question is if there is a way build bundle to not take care about its order in html file?

EDIT:

This is how it looks my architecture, i have to javascript files:

`lib.js` - which is external liblary written by someone else

`myBudnle.js` - my code built using browserify via gulp:

```
var build = getBuildType();

var b = browserify({
    entries: build.src,
    debug: true,
    standalone: "myBundle"
});

return b.bundle()
    .pipe(source(build.src))
    .pipe(rename(build.name))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})).on("error", gutil.log)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(build.bin))
```

and browserify-shim configuration:
  
  `"browserify-shim": {
    "lib": "global:LIB"
  },`

then i have index.html file and i include both js files but i have to do this in specific order

```
<head lang="en">
 <script src="./lib/lib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./lib/myBundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

when i change the order(i generate html file automatically so this can happen often) LIB is undefined in `myBundle.js`, and i have to reorder files manually. Since i have only 2 files it's not a problem but still, i would like to avoid it and don't care about this order by myself.

Comment: Don't hesitate to post some code to illustrate your post and what you want to achieve

Comment: right, i've edited post with example